# How To Mail Merge a Document With Both A Numbered List and If/Then Conditionals, When Some Lines May Be Empty

Tags: microsoft-word-2011

I am mail-merging a letter and ran into a problem with how numbered lists and if/then/else conditionals interact. Can any Microsoft Word experts help me out? :-)

Imagine a numbered list like so:

`1. You are awesome
 2. You are not awesome
 3. This is something else`

Now, imagine that the items that appear next to #1-2 are mutually exclusive. Thus, there are two desired possible results after a mail merge:

**DESIRED OUTPUT FOR AWESOME CASE**

`1. You are awesome
 2. This is something else`

OR

**DESIRED OUTPUT FOR NOT AWESOME CASE**

`1. You are not awesome
 2. This is something else`

The actual output is like so:

**ACTUAL OUTPUT FOR AWESOME CASE**

`1. You are awesome
 2. 
 3. This is something else`

**ACTUAL OUTPUT FOR UNAWESOME CASE**

`1. 
 2. You are not awesome
 3. This is something else`

Here is the code that I'm using:

`{ IF {MERGEFIELD IS_AWESOME} = "x" "You are awesome"} }
{ IF {MERGEFIELD IS_NOT_AWESOME} = "x" "You are not awesome"} }`

These lines have a "numbered list" format applied to it. (I know of no way of making a line item appear as a numbered list without using the standard "numbered list" button.)

I can conceive of a workaround in which I use nested if statements to suppress empty lines, by merging all the conditions of numbered items 1-3. But my actual example has 12 lines, and the number of if-then statements would be exponentially large.

Is there a direct way of making Microsoft Word generate my desired output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you include the respective returns in your formula, it would work:

`{ IF {MERGEFIELD IS_NOT_AWESOME} = "x" "You are not awesome<RET>"} }`

because when the formula removes the text (IF is not true), the return is also removed, so you don't get a blank line with a number.

you will have to remove your now 'additional' returns, and the IFs will be in one continuous stream, which is optically a bit a nuisance - but it should work; I have used that before:

`{ IF {MERGEFIELD IS_AWESOME} = "x" "You are awesome<RET>"} }{ IF {MERGEFIELD IS_NOT_AWESOME} = "x" "You are not awesome<RET>"} }`

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Your insight of putting all the IF MERGEFIELDs on one line is genius. :-)

Note for others: if your bullets/numbered-items has multiple lines (requiring a carriage-return of sorts), you can use a shift-enter to prevent Word from adding bullets/numbers to the subsequent lines.